# Assumptions of path analysis when multivariate normal distribution is violated

Tags: assumptions, structural-equation-modeling, robust-standard-error, path-model

I'm creating my first path analysis model with lavaan (R package). The assumption of multivariate normal distribution, however, is violated. Also, in the regression M1 ~ X1 + X2 (mediator ~ exogenous variables) there is heteroskedacity. Can I fit the model with a robust method (Satorra-Bentler) and then I am fine, or is it not that easy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. That gives you correct standard error in the presence of heteroskedasticity

Some people argue that using robust (Satorra-Bentler, Huber-White, sandwich) estimators means that you are getting the right standard errors on the wrong model - my favorite reference is Freedman: https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~census/mlesan.pdf .

Also, you can bootstrap.

Comment: If all variables are observed, you don't need to go into covariance modeling, and just run this as a system of regression models. Is that how `lavaan` does it? I pledge ignorance. In Stata, this would be [reg3](https://www.stata.com/manuals/rreg3.pdf)... it does not seem to have a `robust` option, but at least you can bootstrap them.

Comment: Lavaan fits it with ML,using covariance modeling.

Comment: OK, so it is a multivariate normal -- is it MVN of the variables marginally, or of the residuals?

Comment: @StasK MVN of the residuals.